# how to get RTP payload which is transported with TCP (about removing header)

Tags: tcp, udp, gstreamer, rtp

I am setting up kind of media player. And I want to get RTP data in TCP packet for media play.

For getting data, i should remove header parts. And i found 2 ways.

**way [1]**
TCP packet

```
[$ - 1byte][Transport Channel - 1byte][RTP data length - 2bytes][RTP data]
```

**way [2]** TCP packet

in rfc4571 standard (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4571#page-3)

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
---------------------------------------------------------------
|             LENGTH            |  RTP or RTCP packet ...     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I found two tcp packet structure.
So if i follow way [1], i should remove 4bytes(1+1+2), but way [2], i should remove 2bytes only.

Actually, i implements my program like way [1], but in gst-plugins-good, rtpstreamdepay plugin implements it follows way [2] and Android also.

So does removing 2bytes are rignt?
or is it old & new standard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you are looking at two different things here.

**Way 1:** Means RTSP interleaving. So all RTP/RTCP channels are transmitted over the RTSP control connection. Since you are dealing with a single connection in this case you need additional information which communication channel the data you are sending belongs to.

**Way 2:** Is simply TCP framing for UDP data. Since TCP is a continuous stream you are missing out implicit length information that UDP datagrams provide. Since the protocol itself does not have such information by itself it is hereby provided by a 16 bit length field before the actual payload.

Comment: Thank you, So Could you please let me know whether i understand well or not? 
I understand way 1 is just for RTSP message such as PLAY, SETUP and real stream data is sent like way 2. Is it right?

Comment: No, **Way1** is for tunneling the data through the RTSP channel. It is one possible operation mode. **Way2** uses a dedicated connection - as regular RTP transmission would do but over TCP instead of UDP. It really depends which mode you establish between client and server.

Comment: Oh, ok i appreciate :) Thank you!